# Fedora PDO driver not found

Tags: php, pdo, fedora

This is really buggin me right now, all q&a I've read dont fix my problem. I've read in php manual that the PDO "driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0." I have php 5.5.18.

php_info() shows:

```
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
```

Im using fedora, and:

```
yum install php-pdo
```

givs:

```
php-pdo-5.5.19-3.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Some code

```
$dsn = '
mysql:host=' . MY_HOST . '
;dbname=' . MY_DB . '
;charset=utf8;"';
$user = MY_USER;
$password = MY_PASS;


    try {
        $this->_dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $this->_dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

This givs me:

```
Connection failed: could not find driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had linebreaks in my DSN string, I think that was the problem.

I've changed it to:

```
    $host = MY_HOST;
    $db = MY_DB;
    $user = MY_USER;
    $password = MY_PASS;

    try {
        $this->_dbh = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8;", 
            $user, 
            $password
            );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        printf(
            'Connection failed: %s<br>',
            $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
```

Comment: yup that could be the problem also. PHP should say error in DSN string or something similar instead of "Connection failed: could not find driver". Misleading.

Answer (score 0):

have you restarted the web server?

when you issue

```
yum install php-pdo
```

and it gives

```
php-pdo-5.5.19-3.fc20.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

which is fine and dandy but you need to issue:

> sudo service httpd stop/start or restart or sudo /etc/init.d/httpd stop/start restart

to load the extension to apache webserver otherwise no matter what else you do to it won't work. the driver is enabled but you need to issue a web server restart to make it load the extension!

Comment: Yes I restarted the Apache server... Found a soultion now.